# Want to disable primary menu for mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu, navigation, hide

Need a CSS code that will disable the primary menu on mobile screens:

```
main-nav id="menu-primary-menu"

"menu-primary-menu" class="mobile-navigation">
```

I think there's a conflict with the theme to prevent it.

**My problem:**

I haven't been able to find the menu-primary-menu code in Functions.php either to disable the mobile class.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and update your question. It is pretty difficult to answer a question that is so vague

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following custom CSS code in style.css file of your theme:

```
.mobile-navigation{
  display: none!important;
}
```